# How to pass in values and headers via Ruby basic authentication?

Tags: ruby, http, basic-authentication

I'm trying to pass in certain values and headers via Ruby but not sure how to do it. What I have so far:

```
  uri = URI.parse('http://jira.test.local/rest/zapi/latest/execution')

  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  req.basic_auth 'userid', 'password'
  res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http| http.request(req)}
  puts res.body

  values   = "{\n    \"issueId\": 32640,\n    \"versionId\": \"11163\",\n    \"cycleId\": \"5\",\n    \"projectId\": 10460\n,\n    \"status\": \"1\"}"
  headers  = {:content_type => "application/json"}

  Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do | http |
          response = http.post(req, values)
          puts response.body
  end
```

I'm getting this error right now:

```
{"status":{"1":{"id":1,"color":"#75B000","description":"Test was executed and passed successfully.","name":"PASS"},"2":{"id":2,"color":"#CC3300","description":"Test was executed and failed.","name":"FAIL"},"3":{"id":3,"color":"#F2B000","description":"Test execution is a work-in-progress.","name":"WIP"},"4":{"id":4,"color":"#6693B0","description":"The test execution of this test was blocked for some reason.","name":"BLOCKED"},"-1":{"id":-1,"color":"#A0A0A0","description":"The test has not yet been executed.","name":"UNEXECUTED"}},"executions":[],"currentlySelectedExecutionId":""}
      undefined method `empty?' for #<Net::HTTP::Get GET> (NoMethodError)
      /Users/fyousuf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:27:in `initialize'
      /Users/fyousuf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/request.rb:14:in `initialize'
      /Users/fyousuf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1390:in `new'
      /Users/fyousuf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1390:in `send_entity'
      /Users/fyousuf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1179:in `post'
      ./features/step_definitions/zapi_farooq.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      /Users/fyousuf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
      /Users/fyousuf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:582:in `start'
      ./features/step_definitions/zapi_farooq.rb:31:in `/^I test zapi update$/'
      features/zapi_farooq.feature:4:in `* I test zapi update'
```

The first line of the output is good, it's giving me the proper outpul from the res.body, but after that is the error.

Summary: I want to go to the uri, authenticate with creds and post with the values provided and with the proper headers (all using Ruby).

I'm trying to create a new execution as per this API: http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#executionresourceapis (Create a new Execution)

Comment: Can you post the full debugging so we know which line is having the error? I do not think the issue is with the basic_auth though. Also, instead of storing your JSON in a string... `require 'json'` and then do `values = {:key => "values"}.to_json`

Comment: While Net::HTTP is powerful, I'd recommend looking at [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb), [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), [httpclient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient), [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) or [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client). They make this sort of stuff easier.

Comment: Skram - I've updated the post with the full output, yes you are right the error is not with the basic_auth. Tin Man, I've tried a bunch of stuff, and I've just gone back to the basics, but I'll give those other ones a shot too.

Comment: Skram - the last 4 lines are what is messing up, I tried commenting it out and there was no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around I got it to work with:

```
  values   = "{\n    \"status\": 2\n}"
  headers  = {:content_type => "application/json"}
  response = RestClient::Resource.new 'http://jira.test.local/rest/zapi/latest/execution/343/execute', 'username', 'password'
  response.put values, headers
  puts response
  puts response.body
```

Gives output of:

```
  http://jira.test.local/rest/zapi/latest/execution/343/execute
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Also it changes the value of the issue in Jira (intended goal).

I just used RestClient b/c the original docs (http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#executionresourceapis) were using it and got some help here too: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client